# Dango: How to get the sum with filters

Tags: django, django-models, datatables

I have a model:

```
class SalesOrder(models.Model):
   area_coordinator = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
   order_number = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
   quantity = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I need to get the sum of the quantity based in area_coordinator.

Thank in advance.

Comment: Does _"based in area_coordinator"_ mean something like you have a variable like `area_coordinator` and you would be filtering `SalesOrder.objects.filter(area_coordinator=area_coordinator)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply [aggregate the sum](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/aggregation/) like this if you want to filter by `area_coordinator`:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
value = SalesOrder.objects.filter(area_coordinator='some value').aggregate(total=Sum('quantity'))['total']
```

But, if you want to `GROUP BY` the `area_coordinator` and get their sum, then try like this:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
SalesOrder.objects.values('area_coordinator').annotate(total=Sum('quantity')).values('area_coordinator', 'total')
```

Comment: Great it solved my problem by using Group By  and getting their sum. Thanks a lot!